# Kotlin - Assigning a static class reference to a variable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

"**R, BuildConfig, DataBinding and BR**" classes in Android are created according to the package name declared in AndroidManifest.xml.

When using them in a class, this package name is imported according to its path. We don't want this because it complicates PRs.

For this, I created a class like the one below.

```
object App {
     val BuildConfig: BuildConfig get() = BuildConfig()
     val R: R get() = R()
     val BR: BR get() = BR()
}
```

But for example, when I try to access `App.R.layout`, your "**layout**" section gets red. So I can't access those statements this way.

For example, classes are automatically created in the following types.

```
public final class BuildConfig {}
public final class R extends Object {}
public final class BR extends Object {}
```

I guess I need to assign a static class reference to a variable.

Do you have a solution suggestion?

Comment: There is no such thing as static class reference in Java (and you are using Java classes from Kotlin). You shouldn't access static members as they are instance members. Anyway, what does it mean that package names complicate PRs? They don't change with time. How are these package names different than package names of any other class?

Comment: Yeah, I think this was the driving motivation for why Kotlin uses `object`s instead. Anyway, even if you could do this, it would make your code more complicated everywhere any one of these static references were used. And as @broot says, how is it any different from any other class you import? Modified import statements in a PR are trivial. As long as the code compiles and unit tests don't start failing, you don't even need to look at modified import lines when reviewing a PR.

Comment: We created another project by changing the name of one of our projects. From time to time, we open PR to each other and combine the codes. In order to avoid conflict, we left the file path names the same and changed the package name only in AndroidManifestte.xml. Since automatically generated codes such as R, BR, BuildConfig are generated according to the package name, conflicts occur in the imported places. So I want to access them from a class with the same file path.

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, so I may say something stupid, but wouldn't it be better to only set different application Ids and leave the package name the same? Changing the package name may have more consequences than just `R` location. For example, in XML files we sometimes reference our namespace, which is also named after the package name in the manifest. See this doc for setting application id: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module